# How do websites keep track of IP addresses

Tags: php, html, ip-address, remote-server

I have created a website and I want to allow specific IP addresses to be able to visit this website. 
After some research I found out that IP addresses might change everyday. Is there any way to obtain the new addresses?

Comment: The correct way to formulate it is 'IP addresses might change'. It depends on your ISP, call them. Otherwise use something with a login.

Comment: Only dynamic IPs gets changed not the Static IPs. You can allow the Static IPs to access your website.

Comment: As you said yourself, some people will have dynamic IP addresses - so either you add allow new IPs each day, or you throw the concept overboard that his will work - and use a regular member system instead e.g.

Comment: Use something with login. At simplest .htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP Addresses change depending on the ISP of the user viewing your website. Some will be assigned a static IP, while many home users may be assigned a dynamic IP that could change on a varying basis.

There are a few different options to handling user authentication, with varying levels of usability:

- Use a login form and create users. You will have to create a database to store encrypted passwords and other user data.
- Use a login with IP address whitelisting. You can detect the origin of the server request using the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable in PHP. Note that if the user is going through a proxy, you will be returned the proxy IP and not the users. You can require a login from anyone outside your array of whitelisted IPs.
- A small sample script to set up your database:

  ```
  $ msyql -u root -pYourPassword
  > CREATE DATABASE mysite;
  > CREATE TABLE users (id TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(30), password VARCHAR(60), email VARCHAR(30), PRIMARY KEY (id));
  ```

That's it for creating a very simple database. For security, you should always salt passwords prior to passing them through the MySQL PASSWORD() function.

- If you aren't comfortable using a database, you can manage user login credentials using htaccess. It is simple and offers no extra fringe benefits or manageability that would come with a programmatic login.

  ```
  #just a basic login
  AuthType Basic

  AuthName "Login Required"
  #the absolute path to your htpasswd. you can use relative, just be conscious if you move either file
  AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
  #if you don't have this, your already limited security is blown
  Require valid-user
  ```
- Wherever the .htpasswd is according to the htaccess, you will have a file `.htpasswd` with one line per user that looks something like:

  ```
  john:$apr1$j08c8l7h$ck52z9GqO0VTgKY5OMerV0
  ```
- Whenever using the .htaccess method, you should own and chmod 600 the files to ensure only the Apache user can read them:

  ```
  chown www-data:www-data .htaccess && chmod 600 .htaccess

  chown www-data:www-data /path/to/.htpasswd && chmod 600 .htpasswd
  ```

I would *highly* recommend using a standard login system with your information stored in a MySQL (or postgres, oracle, etc) database. You noted yourself that IP addresses do change, and frequently updating and managing access to a site using only a list of IP addresses is neither efficient or secure.